# Redis Connection via socket on Node.js

Tags: sockets, node.js, redis

Because of shared hosting, my redis server on the target host does not run on a port, but on a very specific socket, which can be connected to via the socket file, only accessible to my user.

However, I have not found how I can specify connection via a socket in the `node_redis` and `connect-redis` packages, the ones I want to use.

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** My answer below is not really correct. It turns out that the solution in the issue I mention below actually still works. It's more of a coincidence, IMO, but you can do something like this, and it should work:

```
var redis = require('redis'),
    client = redis.createClient('/tmp/redis.sock');
```

As you see from the code snippet below, this will get passed to `net.createConnection` which will connect to the unix socket `/tmp/redis.sock`.

**Old answer:**

There is a closed issue about this [node_redis/issues/204](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/issues/204). It seems, thought, that the underlying node.js [net.createConnection](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectionlistener) API has since changed. It looks as though it would be a quite small fix in node_redis' `exports.createClient` function:

```
exports.createClient = function (port_arg, host_arg, options) {
    var port = port_arg || default_port,
        host = host_arg || default_host,
        redis_client, net_client;

    net_client = net.createConnection(port, host);

    redis_client = new RedisClient(net_client, options);

    redis_client.port = port;
    redis_client.host = host;

    return redis_client;
};
```

It seems as though `net.createConnection` will attempt to connect to a unix socket if it's called with one argument, that looks like a path. I suggest you implement a fix and send a pull request, since this seems like something worth supporting.

Comment: If you want to pass in options as well, you can do `redis.createClient('/tmp/redis.sock', null, { options })`

Answer (score -1):

### There is no longer a [connect string](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/master/index.js#L1216)...

```
var client = redis.createClient(9000); // Open a port on localhost
var client = redis.createClient('/tmp/redis.sock'); // Open a unix socket
var client = redis.createClient(9000, 'example.com');
```

This, and options are documented on the [README](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#rediscreateclient).